# Filter Outlook Mails by Partial String or Partial Text in Subject

Tags: python

Hi Tried to search the solution by which I can filter the outlook mail by the part of string exist into that rather than filtering the mail on complete subject.I am using win32com

```
import win32com.client
if mail.subject.contains('Filter Text'):
 message.Unread=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below

```
if 'Your String' in str(message.subject):
```